How can the react state dispatch be used in an effect before its definition?
The following code works as expected and displays the number 1:
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function StateTest() {
  useEffect(() => {
    setX(1);
  });

  const [x, setX] = useState(0);

  return <div className="w-64 bg-black p-8 text-center text-white">{x}</div>;
}

How can this be when the following code fails to execute in node or in the browser:
function callbackLogger(callback) {
  console.log(callback());
}

function main() {
  callbackLogger(() => {
    return helloWorld();
  });

  const helloWorld = () => {
    return "Hello World!";
  };
}

main();

When run this in the firefox terminal it produces the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'helloWorld' before initialization

How can this be? Is React reorganizing my code? Is there something magical about react dispatches?

Hello there is another question related to this Hoisting in react components. How does it work?. There is some anwser to your question

If you re-define helloWorld using the function keyword instead of const, it works.
function callbackLogger(callback) {
  console.log(callback());
}

function main() {
  callbackLogger(() => {
    return helloWorld();
  });

  function helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!";
  };
}

main();

The short explanation for this is Declaration Hoisting.
The MDN Website goes into this in a lot of detail.
Hoisting allows your functions and classes to be accessed before they are declared. That's why the function declared with the function keyword did not give an error.
However, this does not work with function expressions.

That's interesting but I don't think it is correct because the react dispatch / setter is assigned to a const inside the function
